# What's the difference between having a 'terrible time', and having a 'very bad time'?

Tags: difference, phrase-meaning

I need to explain the difference between having a 'terrible time', and having a 'very bad time' to non-native English speakers, but I expect these expressions to be used interchangeably.

Is there a difference?

How can I explain it in very basic language?

Comment: There isn't really any difference. "Terrible" means "very bad," and a "having terrible time" means "having a very bad time." They can be used interchangeably. Why do you think there would be a difference?

Comment: I personally don't think there would he a difference, but the text book lists both as if they were different. It does the same with "to have a lovely time" and "to have a great time."

Comment: Normally I would just say they are the same, but I'm a student teacher and the person marking can be very nitpicky.

Comment: I personally don't think that there's any real difference. But if you wanted to be pedantic you could say that "terrible" is slightly stronger than "very bad", so someone having a terrible time is worse off than someone having a very bad time.

Comment: In most situations they express  practically the same thing.

Comment: Can you repost the part of the textbook that makes them look different?  I'm curious exactly what it says.

Comment: @stangdon It could be this one: [English Unlimited Elementary A and B Teacher's Pack](https://books.google.com/books?id=fYu6vM3euFQC&pg=PA47) (under TASK VOCABULARY Good and bad experiences, near the bottom-right corner).

Comment: Welcome to ELL, StrugglingTeacher! Have you looked up *terrible* in a dictionary (or a few of them)? If so, please describe what you found in your question, and why any information you found did not resolve it. (It's fine if you describe what you have found and explain if you still have a question.) If this question needs only a dictionary to resolve, it's off-topic for our site and may be closed. Please see *help* below, then under *asking,* see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As it stands, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.]

Comment: Counterintuitive as it seems, I'd say "terrible" is closer to a neutral way to say this, or at least easier to get right. Think about how you'd actually say "I'm having a *very* bad time" in practice. With proper emphasis, it has much more effect, but without emphasis it just sounds weird and formal.

Answer (score 1):

A terrible time and a very bad time *can* both mean the same thing, ie not enjoying yourself ("I'm having a terrible/very bad time at this baseball game"), but in a different context "A terrible time" could mean struggling ("I'm having a terrible time trying to decipher his handwriting").

This second usage sounds vaguely British to me, and I think the more common American English equivalent would be "having a hard time", or "difficult time".